# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mysql, php, mysql-workbench

I have created a PHP site using MySQL. It works well on localhost. However, when I moved it to a remote server, it stopped working.

The error shown is:

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

I am using MySQL Workbench. How do I go about resolving this error?

Answer (score 1):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'user'@'11.22.33.44' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

What this means is that you lack privileges connecting to the mysql database from the remote host. What you basicly need to do is to grant those privileges with the above statement.